# How to check a specific coloumn inside a query with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

im using the below query to obtain a set of tables.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables a WHERE table_schema = 'mydb'
AND table_name LIKE 'table_%'
```

then it returns table_1,table_2,table_3 etc

inside these tables theres a coloumn called **"timestamp"** which represtents the date, my question is can i just obtain tables which has timestamps within the last week only.

the condition

```
TABLE_NAME.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR)
```

i tried the one below for no avail

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables a WHERE table_schema = 'mydb'
AND table_name LIKE 'table_%' 
AND TABLE_NAME.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)
```

can anybody help me on this

Comment: Take a look at information_schema.columns :)